# insert current date in oracle database using jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to insert current date into Oracle sql.I had set the datatype to be DATE in oracle sql and changed the date format to DD-MM-YYYY.Now I am trying to insert current date as follows.But I am getting some error as shown below.Don't know what is wrong

```
String sql6 = "insert into account(acc_no,acc_type,primary_phone_number,people_in_plan,acc_activated_date,acc_deactivated_date) values('"+n1+"','"+acctype+"','"+primaryphoneno+"','"+number_of_people+"',?,?)";      
Stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql6);
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MM-YYYY");
Date date1 = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Stmt.setString(5, sdf.format(date1));
Stmt.setNull(6, java.sql.Types.DATE);
Stmt.executeUpdate();
```

java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setStringInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5386)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setString(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5374)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setString(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:282)

Comment: Unless you need the date for the rest of the processing, why not just insert sysdate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your column indexes are incorrect. They should be 1 and 2 respective.

```
Stmt.setString(1, sdf.format(date1));
Stmt.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.DATE);
```

Comment: I changed it still I am getting the error as  ORA-01861: literal does not match format string.So, I had formatted DATE in Oracle sql. So, I generally insert values as follows: INSERT  into t  (start_date) values (TO_DATE('19990725', 'YYYYMMDD')); Here what should I change in the code to get the current date and insert it into the table?

Comment: Use lowercase yyyy, not uppercase YYYY for year. Use lowercase dd, not uppercase DD for day.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");`

Answer (score 0):

please user `statement.setObject(1, new java.sql.Date());`instead

Comment: @Pamparanpa: But I have formatted the date in oracle sql. Generally when I insert date in oracle I do as follows :  INSERT  into t  (start_date) values (TO_DATE('19990725', 'YYYYMMDD'));  so now its showing error.Here what should I change in the code to get the current date and insert it into the table in that format?